# Rspec check the template after a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here is my create action for users:

```
def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { 
                    redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(@user) 
                    flash[:success] = "Successfully created"
                }
            end
        else
            render :new
            flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong"
        end
    end
```

My test is looking like this:

```
context "POST methods" do

    describe "#create" do
        it "renders the edit template" do
            post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
            expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
        end
    end
end
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Admin::UsersController POST methods #create renders the edit template
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
       expecting <"edit"> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/admin/users/80/edit>
```

I want to check if the edit.html.haml file is rendered after creating a user. What am I doing wrong?

**Update #1**
I do check for redirect in another test, this is my full test suite:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::UsersController, type: :controller do

    render_views    

    context "POST methods" do

        describe "#create" do
            it "using valid params" do

                expect{
                    post :create, user: { email: "something@hello.com", password: "long12345678" }
                    }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
                # get user_path('1')
            end

            it "redirects to the edit page after saving" do
                post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
                user = User.last
                expect(response).to redirect_to(edit_admin_user_path(user.id))
            end

            it "renders the edit template" do
                post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
                user = User.last
                expect {
                    redirect_to(edit_admin_user_path(user.id))  
                }.to render_template(:edit)
            end

            context "it redirects to new" do
                it "if user has no valid mail" do
                    post :create, user: { email: "something", password: "long12345678" }
                    expect(response).to render_template(:new)
                end
                it "if user has no valid password" do
                    post :create, user: { email: "something@mail.com", password: "short" }  
                    expect(response).to render_template(:new)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What I want is to actually check if the edit template is rendered. Because with `expect(response).to redirect_to(edit_admin_user_path(user))` it does **not** check the template. This test passes even if I have **no** edit.html.haml file at all.

Comment: To ensure that *edit.html.haml* exists, you need to write tests for `edit` action, not the `create` action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're testing `create` action you should just check correctness of redirect. In this action you're not actually rendering `edit` template, but you're just making redirect to the `edit` path of created entity. So this is the thing you should check.

```
describe "#create" do
    it "redirects to the edit path" do
        post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
        expect(response).to redirect_to(edit_admin_user_path(User.last))
    end
end
```

Then you should have another test for `edit` action, where you're checking template rendering. That will mean that after redirect in create action you also will see the proper template.

Comment: Updated my question, I'm already checking the explicit redirect. But this test passes even if I have no edit.html.haml file at all.

Comment: @mohnstrudel, I think you're overtesting. When you're testing `create` action you should just check correctness of redirect. Then you should have another test for `edit` action, where you're checking template rendering. That will mean that after redirect in `create` action you also will see the proper template.

Comment: Great, thank you! This flaw in my logic was indeed the case. I've got this test now, and it works properly:
  `context "GET methods" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) } 
    let(:created_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    describe "#edit" do
      it "renders edit template" do
        get :edit, id: created_user.id
        expect(response).to render_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end`

Could you consider changing your initial answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @mohnstrudel thanks, I've changed a bit, but anyway - comments are also a part of discussion and answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to `edit_admin_user_path` after successfully saving the User in your controller action. But, you're testing `render` in the test instead.

Update your test as below.

```
context "POST methods" do

describe "#create" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
  end
  it "renders the edit template" do
    post :create, user: @user
      expect(response).to redirect_to(edit_admin_user_path(@user))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I do have this test already, but it does not check if edit template is present. Meaning, when I have _no_ edit.html.haml this test still passes.
I tried this code:
`it "renders the edit template" do
    post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
    user = User.last
    expect {
     redirect_to(edit_admin_user_path(user.id)) 
    }.to render_template(:edit)
   end`
but this leads to an error:
`You must pass an argument rather than a block to use the provided matcher (render template matcher "edit"), or the matcher must implement `supports_block_expectations?`.`